# problema con android sdk tools (android emulator) en visual studio 2019 Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

soy noob en esto de la programación para móviles. Debo empezar a crear aplicaciones por Xamarin, lo he instalado como todos los videos. He descargado visual studio 2019 community 16.10.3 desde la página oficial, en las cargas de trabajo, seleccioné Xamarin e instaló todo normalmente.

Creo el proyecto de Xamarin Forms multiplataforma para Android, IOS, etc. (Actualmente solamente me interesa ejecutar Android). Cuando ejecuto el proyecto con Android Emulator, aparece que falta la instancia de Android SDK Tools, a pesar que ya tengo instalado todo. Por más que instale las plataformas, herramientas y esté configurado todo por defecto, no hay manera que pueda crear un dispositivo movil.

Pueden ver el problema y todas las configuraciones que tengo en el siguiente video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ev9-KIR6sCg

No sé si tengo que tener instalado Android Studio para que funcione con Visual Studio 2019, aunque en los tutoriales que he visto en youtube solamente instalan la carga de trabajo de Xamarin y ya tienen todos los emuladores corriendo. Ya he desinstalado e instalado Visual Studio 2019 muchas veces y vuelto a instalar, incluso en varias computadoras y siempre tengo el problema que no me deja configurar los emuladores y que me dice que Android SDK Tools falta, por más que seleccione instalar sigue apareciendo que falta la instancia de Android SDK Tools.

**SOLUCIÓN QUE ME FUNCIONÓ:**
Después de estar buscando por todos lados alguna solución a este error, que aparentemente solamente unos pocos hemos sido los suertudos jeje. Tuve que investigar bastante y unir pasos de todo un poco hasta que funcionó, les dejo mi solución:

1. Copiar la carpeta "lib" de la ruta: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\cmdline-tools\2.1". Hacia la ruta: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools".
2. Desinstalar e instalar Android SDK Tools desde la opción de "Android SDK Manager" en Visual Studio 2019.

Me imagino será un problema de esta release de Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Qué problema más raro. ¿De casualidad será porque te estan faltando el componente Google Play Services de Tools? Si no es eso, podrías intentar verificar con Android Studio qué es lo que tienes instalado.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, traté pero no funcionó. Gracias por tu sugerencia!

Comment: @KENNYEDUARDOPEREZAREVALO tu solución debe ir en la zona de respuestas y no en tu pregunta, por favor edita y arregla dicho detalle

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo unas capturas para que tengas como referencias sobre la configuracion para que levante el emulador y otras cosas al momento de enchufar un telefono. No es la mejor forma de dar una respuesta pero no veo otra manera de mostrar la respuesta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por tu sugerencia bro, al final lo puse así pero no funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIÓN QUE ME FUNCIONÓ: Después de estar buscando por todos lados alguna solución a este error, que aparentemente solamente unos pocos hemos sido los suertudos jeje. Tuve que investigar bastante y unir pasos de todo un poco hasta que funcionó, les dejo mi solución:

Copiar la carpeta "lib" de la ruta: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\cmdline-tools\2.1". Hacia la ruta: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools".
Desinstalar e instalar Android SDK Tools desde la opción de "Android SDK Manager" en Visual Studio 2019.
Me imagino será un problema de esta release de Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta que das es la correcta, es necesario copiar la carpeta que mencionas a la ruta indicada, desinstalar el Android SDK tools y volverlos a instalar, mi error se debía a que había instalado todo del Android sdk tools.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/370381)